# Weird vertical div flex behavior

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I need to create markup of simple image box js control.
It should have main image container along with the thumbnail images region. The last should be located on the top, bottom, right or left from the main image region.

I almost done with the markup using "flex" approach.
It works great when thumbnails region is horizontal (located on the top or bottom):

http://jsfiddle.net/z9rq73ub/

but it fails for the case of vertical thumbnails region (left or right from the main image): "thumbs-container" div overflows while I want "thumbs" div to overflow. Here is my test markup:

```
<div class="frame" style="height: 250px; width: 250px; border: 1px solid black;">
<div class="image" style="background:red; margin:5px;"></div>
<div class="thumbs-container" style="margin:5px;">
    <div class="back" style="background:orange"></div>
    <div class="thumbs" style="background:blue;">
       <div class="thumb" style="background:green; margin:3px;"></div>
       <div class="thumb" style="background:green; margin:3px;"></div>
       <div class="thumb" style="background:green; margin:3px;"></div>
       <div class="thumb" style="background:green; margin:3px;"></div>
       <div class="thumb" style="background:green; margin:3px;"></div>
       <div class="thumb" style="background:green; margin:3px;"></div>
       <div class="thumb" style="background:green; margin:3px;"></div>
       <div class="thumb" style="background:green; margin:3px;"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="forth" style="background:orange"></div>
</div>
```

```
.frame {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}

.image {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  order: 0;
}

.thumbs-container {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  order: 1;
}

.back{
  flex: 0 0 30px; 
}

.forth{
  flex: 0 0 30px; 
}

.thumbs {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.thumb {
  flex: 0 0 30px;
}
```

Please, see
http://jsfiddle.net/d6ddL6jn/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```css
.thumbs { flex: 1 0 auto; }
```

Use

```css
.thumbs { flex: 1; }
```

That is, set `flex-basis` to `0`.

```css
.frame {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row; /* row,column */
}
.image {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  order: 0; /* 1 */
}
.thumbs-container {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column; /* row,column */
  order: 1; /* 0 */
}
.back {
  flex: 0 0 30px;
}
.forth {
  flex: 0 0 30px;
}
.thumbs {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column; /* row,column */
  overflow: hidden;
}
.thumb {
  flex: 0 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame" style="height: 250px; width: 250px; border: 1px solid black;">
  <div class="image" style="background:red; margin:5px;"></div>
  <div class="thumbs-container" style="margin:5px;">
    <div class="back" style="background:orange"></div>
    <div class="thumbs" style="background:blue;">
      <div class="thumb" style="background:green; margin:3px;"></div>
      <div class="thumb" style="background:green; margin:3px;"></div>
      <div class="thumb" style="background:green; margin:3px;"></div>
      <div class="thumb" style="background:green; margin:3px;"></div>
      <div class="thumb" style="background:green; margin:3px;"></div>
      <div class="thumb" style="background:green; margin:3px;"></div>
      <div class="thumb" style="background:green; margin:3px;"></div>
      <div class="thumb" style="background:green; margin:3px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="forth" style="background:orange"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```